# JQuery datepicker with dependency

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any JQuery predefine code where two datepicker can be setup in one page with dependency?

For example: 'To date' and 'From date' where 'From date' must be greater than or equal to 'To date'.

If not, then what will be the code for this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look on the jqueryui website - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

any number of datepicker to html element with class .datepick 
and now comparing date u need check `var date1= new date($('#dateinput').val());` greater than
`var date1= new date($('#dateinput2').val());`